# OBIEE adding an integer to date

Tags: obiee

I am looking to add a number of days (column 1- integer) to a date (column 2- date) to create another date in the future (column 3- date).

What is the code required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for giving me a great start. Here is what ended up working:

TimestampAdd(SQL_TSI_DAY,"Customer"."Cycle Days","Customer"."Next Inspection Date")

"Customer"."Cycle Days" - # (integer) of days to be added to the date
"Customer"."Next Inspection Date" - date

Answer (score 3):

Try using this formula for column3

```
TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,CAST("Table"."Column1_int" AS INTEGER), "Table"."Column2_date")
```